# 65536bit long certificate self-signing using openssl fails

Tags: openssl, self-signed-certificate

I created my privatekey & certificate request using `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:65536 > server.cert.csr`. This took some minutes and produced 2 files.

Then I decrypted my private key using `openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.cert.key`

Now I want to self-sign my certificate using `openssl x509 -in server.cert.csr -out server.cert.crt  -req -signkey server.cert.key -days 365` but this results in an error:

```
Signature did not match the certificate request
```

I tried the same procedure using smaller keys (only 4096bits) and then it worked. Is there no way to get a 65536bit long key self-signed?

What exactly is here the problem or is this just a bug? I am sure that I didn't mix private keys or certificate requests.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in openssl, but still - 65kb private key will not get you super-safe-vpn, only a super-slow-one (longer encryption/decryption using longer key) - a value of 8kb should be pretty safe for the next decades. **I would recommend using 4k key**.

It would be actually much safer to rotate the private keys/certificates in a schedule than having a huge encryption key.

Look at this thread and see what crypto experts came up with
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/are-there-practical-upper-limits-of-rsa-key-lengths

Comment: do you know if this bug has already reported?